# R ggplot2 set color line by variable without grouping

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot three different lines with ggplot2 that show the temporal series of three different variable (max, min and mean temperature). The problem comes when I want to set the color for each line/variable.

ggplot command:

```
plot.temp=ggplot(data,aes_string(x="date", y="Tmed",colour="Tmed")) + geom_line() +
  geom_line(data=data,aes_string(x="date",y="Tmin",colour="Tmin")) +
  geom_line(data=data,aes_string(x="date",y="Tmax",colour="Tmax"))
```

I don't use group as each row stands for one single time, not available categories here.

I have tried different optinos found in another posts like `scale_color_manual` but then a `Continuous value supplied to discrete scale` error message appears

You can find data file at http://ubuntuone.com/45LqzkMHWYp7I0d47oOJ02 that can be easily read with `data = read.csv(filename,header=T, sep=",",na.strings="-99.9")`

I'd just like to set the color line manually but can't find the way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to convert `date` to Date object because now it is treated as factor. If date is treated as factor then each `date` value is assumed as separate group.

```
data$date<-as.Date(data$date)
```

Second, as you are using `aes_string()` also `colour="Tmed"` is interpreted as colors that depend from actual `Tmed` values. Use `aes()` and quotes only for `colour=` variable. Also there is no need to repeat `data=` argument in each `geom_line()` because you use the same data frame.

```
ggplot(data,aes(x=date, y=Tmed,colour="Tmed")) + geom_line() +
  geom_line(aes(y=Tmin,colour="Tmin")) +
  geom_line(aes(y=Tmax,colour="Tmax"))
```

Of course you can also melt your data and then you will need only one `geom_line()` call (but still you need to change date column).

```
library(reshape2)
data2<-melt(data[,1:4],id.vars="date")
ggplot(data2,aes(date,value,color=variable))+geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for reshape2, in the beginning I just hated to have a dataframe where I have to have melted dataframe (as opposed to Excel), but now, I just love it

Comment: Thanks @didzis-elferts Both solutions run fine but I still can't choose the colours and labels for the legend. Maybe 'scale_color_manual'?

Comment: By adding `scale_color_manual("Temperatura",values = c('red', 'brown', 'blue'),labels = c('Máxima','Media','Mínima'))` it works fine but this was after some tries and I'm not sure why is working.

Comment: I'm not sure it didn't work for you earlier. This works in both cases  `+scale_color_manual(values=c("black","grey","red"))`